# PHP / BTC Handling users xfers

Tags: php, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

**Hi everyone!**

I'm looking for a minimal PHP / BTC system that allows users to transfer bitcoin into the website, generating a new address for each transfer, and enabling them to withdraw to any address they specify when requested.

To be honest, I find this source very useful: https://github.com/zonedoutspace/BitWallet

But in the other hand, being a development from 2015, I'm worried that there could be some public known security issues on it.

Does anyone have any recommendation about how we could implement it, if it's safe, or if there's any other similar system that would allow us to handle the bitcoin xfers internally?

We already have a working system, database and users.

Kind regards;
Chris C. Russo

Answer (score -1):

After a careful analytic review on the Github repo, the security issues you'll have are the issues you let, like

`1. Cross-Origin Attack
 2. SQL Injection
 3. And More like it`

But you can also make reference to a more recent RPC Project Repo https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc

Comment: Hi Tom, did you really made a code analysis? lol, I also work on IT sec, but you have been quick, Thanks!

Comment: Lol', a quick one... But it's safe anyways